# Wordpress ajax request not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, i make a ajax request on click button and it print the data, but ajax is not giving me any response. Please help me to find out the error.

Here is my code

```
add_action("wp_ajax_delivery_options", "delivery_options");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_delivery_options", "delivery_options");

function delivery_options()
{
    echo json_encode(array('type' => 'success'));
    wp_die();
}

wp_enqueue_script("my-ajax-handle", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/custom.js", array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Ajax

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delivery_option button').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = e.currentTarget.id;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        data: { delivery_option: data },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: what error response you get ? can let me know

Comment: Is the_ajax_script.ajaxurl objects declared somewhere?

Comment: @NealDeveloper nothing in console

Comment: @Aroon no,  i just see the tutorial and copy same as he did

Comment: hmmm. then you will never get the work done. please understand the concepts and try. show us the progress which you made. It will be very helpful for your future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass "callback function name" in `data: { action: 'delivery_options', delivery_option: data },`

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#delivery_option button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.currentTarget.id;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
      data: { action: 'delivery_options', delivery_option: data },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
});})(jQuery);
```